# starting point for a soccer game AI

Tags: ai, steering-behaviors, planning, teamwork

I would like to build a simple but challenging soccer game. I can define simple as not need to be realistic and challenging having a good team sense that could colaborate doing nice plays.

I have read a bunch of resources about the subject and almost all solucitions are based on heuristics to decide the different actions depending on the state of the team (Attacking, Deffending, etc...).

Beside this we have things like steering behavirous for things like "Go get the ball", "Go to this point to block ball/other player", etc...

Could for example a Goal Oriented action Planner help in this subeject? has anyone any experience on this? How would you orquestate all players movement to behave like a team and not like independent entities on the play field but not feel like robots?

I'm looking here for just some guidelines or concepts, I know it is a broad topic but listening for other people that have experience on the subject could be really helpfull.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks a bit too loose to have a concise correct answer fitting our Q&A format here. Would you consider editing your question to make the problem more concrete? Say, outline your plan for your AI based on your reading so far. Describe what this plan does well, and identify a specific gap, concern, or demonstrated problem where the AI may not behave the way you want. Define what you want the AI to do instead in these situations, and users here can help suggest ways to modify your plan to bring it closer in line to the target behaviour you've defined.

Comment: You actually understand quite well what you have to implement, and I suggest you just trying to do it by yourself. But if you need some references\tutorials, there's a pretty good example in Mat Buckland's Programming game AI by example. You should definetly check that out.